# Problemas para carregar o CSS (Spring MVC)

Tags: spring, front-end, spring-mvc

Bom dia pessoa,

revi alguns topicos que apontava problema para carregar o css das jsp usando spring mvc , mas infelizmente eu nao consegui localizar a solucao.

Eu tenho uma jsp (index.jsp) porem quando eu faco o request da pagina o navegador nao consegue logalizar o direito do css.

Poderia me ajudar ?
Segue o link do projeto : https://github.com/Igoralves12/WebErp

Comment: Cadê o index.jsp? No repositório.

Comment: Maury esta no seguinte diretorio WebErp/WebContent/WEB-INF/pages/login/index.jsp